# Issues with Citation formatting and using plainnat

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I just started using Latex and had a couple of things I am not able to figure out.

1. I am trying to change the citation style in my thesis format. It is currently something like

   ```
   Crowe et al.(Cro96)
   ```

   But I want it to look like this

   ```
   Crowe et al.(1996)
   ```
2. Also, my References section is weird. It looks currently like this

   ```
   Crowe, C. T. et al. “Two-Phase Turbulent Flows” (1996).
   ```

   But I would like it to show the names of all the other authors too in the references, obviously(there are three).
3. I tried using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` separately but both give me a similar error

   ```
   ! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

   ! Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \bibliographystyle{apalike}
   ```

As far as I know, I am using natbib as `\RequirePackage[...,backend=bibtex,natbib=true,...]{biblatex}`

But I have no idea how to get this to work. I am an absolute beginner to Latex, so I have no idea if the info I have provided is sufficient, so do feel free to ask me for more if required.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It does not look at all like you're using the `natbib` package. Instead, it very much looks like you're using the `biblatex` package.

Comment: But doesn't natbib=true mean that?

Comment: Indeed, the line you showed loads `biblatex`. But then `\bibliographystyle` is BibTeX syntax. You will need to show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can see what us going on.

Comment: No `natbib=true` only enables `biblatex`'s `natbib` compatibility mode that allows you to use `\citep` instead of `\parencite` etc.

Comment: I will try and make the MWE. Meanwhile, I am using the exact template as here: https://grad.ncsu.edu/students/etd/etd-templates/ the thesis template, version 0.6 inside the zip. Do let me know if that will be sufficient, else I will be working on the MWE anyway.

Comment: It seems the MWE would require the non-standard customized class files too, and I am not sure if a buggy MWE by me will be more convenient to you guys than the working class and tex files inside the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you've adapted the file `YourName-thesis.tex` from the template package for your purposes. In this file, one finds the following passage:

```
\RequirePackage[
            style=alphabetic,%numeric-comp,%authoryear-comp,%
            sorting=nyt,%ynt                    
            hyperref=true, %    
            firstinits=true,%
            backend=bibtex,
            natbib=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxnames=2, %for et al to be used
            maxalphanames=1, %to avoid printing a + for every et al in the abbreviation
            doi=false]{biblatex}
```

The upshot is that (a) the `biblatex` package is used, (b) the "back-end" program is set to `bibtex` (the default nowadays is `biber`), (c) code is loaded to emulate `natbib`-style citation commands (such as `\citet` and `\citep`), and (d) a crude form of the `alpha` citation call-out style is used. If you don't like these defaults, you have to change one or more of the settings.

Comment: Whoa! Changed the style to authoryear-comp and it works! But I am still having the second issue, where the references are showing et al. Also, they have enabled bibliographystyle plainnat and apalike in the as it is in the tex file, but neither work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I increase maxnames to 4 or 5, the references correct themselves but now the citation has all the names too, instead of an et al

Comment: @AyushAgrawal - Do look into what setting the parameter `maxcitenames=2` will do for you. By the way, unless you *must* truncate the number of authors displayed for an entry that features a multitude of authors, I can see no reason for not setting `maxnames=999`.

Comment: maxcitenames=2 after setting maxnames=999 worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AyushAgrawal - Glad I was able to point you in the right direction.